# Find the distinct duplicates in an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm trying to write a method to find duplicate values within an array, and return true when that happens twice (otherwise returning false).

I have something, but for some reason, it doesn't work properly under a certain case:

```
public static boolean twoDuplicates(int[] values) {

    boolean twoDuplicate = false;
    int counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        for(int z = i + 1; z <= values.length - 1; z++){
            if(i != z && values[i] == values[z])
                counter++;
        }
    }
    if(counter == 2)
        twoDuplicate = true;
    return twoDuplicate;
}
```

Now, I tested it out, and it doesn't work when the values are [3,3,3,6,6]. Is there a reason why?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the duplicates HAVE to be distinct.

Comment: What is `counter` returning with that input array?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are just counting the total number of matches. ie you will be matching 3 twice (counter = 3 now) and z once for a total of 4.
When I run this code with the array I get counter = 4;

I think the following code will return the number of distinct duplicates (number with a duplicate, no matter how many times it occurs). This will return 2 for the test array. It first sorts the array, then finds duplicates, ignoring duplicates that have already been counted.

```
public static boolean twoDuplicates(int[] values) {

        boolean twoDuplicate = false;
        int counter = 0;
        Arrays.sort(values);
        int old = values[0];
        boolean numberSeen = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
            if(values[i] == old){
                if(!numberSeen){
                    counter++;
                    numberSeen = true;
                }
            }else{
                numberSeen = false;
                old = values[i];
            }
        }
        if(counter == 2)
            twoDuplicate = true;
        return twoDuplicate;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your existing code you are counting the number of pairs rather than finding duplicates.
You should check counter separately for each 'i'.

```
public static boolean twoDuplicates(int[] values) {

boolean twoDuplicate = false;

for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
int counter = 0;
for(int z = i + 1; z <= values.length - 1; z++){
        if(i != z && values[i] == values[z])
            counter++;
    }
   if(counter == 2) // or if(counter > 1) if finding three duplicates is also fine
      return true;
}

return false;
}
```

Or

```
public static boolean twoDuplicates(int[] values) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
       int counter = 0;
       for(int z = i + 1; z <= values.length - 1; z++)
       {
            if(values[i] == values[z])
            {
                counter++;
                if(counter == 2) // check here if you want 2 or more duplicates
                   return true;
            }
        }
        // check here if you want exactly two duplicates
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your logic, if you have  more than 2 duplicates,the function will return false, maybe you should use "counter>1" for judge, and the counter definition should be placed in the outer iteration. And I think the algorithm is not clever enough.

Answer (score 0):

Situation is like that:

First loop reads first 3. Second loop reads second and third 3s. Counter becomes 2.
First loop reads second 3. Second loop reads third 3. Counter becomes 3.
First loop reads third 3. Second loop cannot find anything. Counter is 3.
First loop reads first 6. Second loop reads second 6. Counter is 4.
First loop reads second 6. Second loop cannot find anything. Counter is 4.

What you need to do is to put that `if( counter == 2 )` after second loop. This will solve your problem.

`if( counter == 2 ) return true;`

Comment: It's better to learn writing algorithms without returning from the middle.

Answer (score 0):

1 . You need to remember the value of the first duplicate pair found.

Otherwise, in a row 3,3,3 - you will find 3 two times.
So store the first duplication value and compare this is not it.

```
int firstDuplicate;


if(i != z && values[i] == values[z]) {

     if (counter == 0) {

          counter++;
          firstDuplicate = values[i];

     } else if (counter == 1 && values[i] != firstDuplicate) {

          counter++;
     }
}
```

2 . `z <= values.length - 1` should be `z < values.length`. As you used in the first `for`.

3 . Always use `{ }` even if the block is single-lined.

**UPD**

4 . Use `break;` to stop iterating when you found what you need.

```
for(){
    for(){

    }
    if(counter == 2) {
        twoDuplicate = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Or better

```
for(int i = 0; i < values.length && counter < 2; i++;){
    for(){

    }
}

return counter >= 2;
```

Comment: I think your logic is right, but for the second if-statement, the firstDuplicate variable wouldn't have been initialized.

I see what you mean, though.

Comment: I did not run it, so yes compiler might show something.. It will not enter the second IF before firstDuplicate is initialized with the correct value, so all is good here :)

Answer (score 0):

this is how I would do it with just one loop

```
    public static boolean twoDuplicates(int[] values) {
    HashSet<Integer> map = new HashSet<Integer>();
    int cont = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (map.contains(values[i])){
            cont++;
            if (cont == 2) 
                return true;
        }           
        else
            map.add(values[i]);

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think it's more depending on whether the need is for performance or simplicity

Comment: The correct solution to this particular issue is no more complex then with Map, I guess. Plus thinking about how to improve the algorithm without using complex structures like Map is a useful habit.